# Flash external file doesn't work in my Symfony project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, symfony

I'm working on my portfolio that I make with Symfony and I'm having problem when adding one of my flash project in my portfolio.

My flash project use external file, so I put a folder with thos file right next to my swf. If I double click my swf, it opens the project correctly and everything works, but when I add the project in my page, it doesn't load the externla file. Here is the structure of my web directory:

web
--bundles
  --public
    --projets (it's french that means projects)
      --flash
        Tech_Boy.swf
        techBoyMediaExternes (this is the external media files)

Here is the code I use to integrate it:

```
<object width="{{ projet.largeur }}" height="{{ projet.hauteur }}"
    classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
    codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/
    pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0">
    <param name="{{ projet.nom }}" value="{{ asset("bundles/public/projets/flash/"~ projet.fichier) }}">
    <embed src="{{ asset("bundles/public/projets/flash/"~ projet.fichier) }}" width="{{ projet.largeur }}" height="{{ projet.hauteur }}">
    </embed>
    </object>
```

I acces my files this way:

```
this._ambianceSon = new Sound();
this._ambianceSon.load(new URLRequest("techBoyMediasExternes/son/Musique_Ambiance.mp3"));
```

And for the pictures, I use a custom class:

```
package classes.medias{

    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;

    public class Image extends Bitmap {

        /*Cette classe permet de récupérer les données BitmapData d'une image chargée dans un Loader
        L'avantage est qu'un objet d'affichage de type Bitmap est moins lourd en mémoire
        qu'un objet Loader*/

        //Constantes de la classe pour quand on dispatch des événements
        public static const IMAGE_CHARGEE:String = "imageChargee";

        //Fonction constructive de la classe
        public function Image(pLien:String) {

            //Lien de l'image externe
            var lien:URLRequest=new URLRequest(pLien);

            //On télécharge l'image
            var loader=new Loader();
            loader.load(lien);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,recupererDatas);

        }

        //Quand l'image externe est chargée, on récupère ses données BitmapData
        private function recupererDatas(pEvt:Event):void {

            //Récupérer l'image chargée dans le Loader
            var imageChargee:Bitmap = pEvt.target.content as Bitmap;

            //Récupérer les données bitmap de l'image chargée
            this.bitmapData = imageChargee.bitmapData;

            //On dispatch l'événement pour dire que l'image est chargée
            this.dispatchEvent(new Event(Image.IMAGE_CHARGEE));

        }

    }//Fermeture de public class Personnage extends Bitmap

}//Fermeture du package
```

Comment: How do you access the file in your flash app? If you use 'bundles/public/projets/flash/' in embed, you should also use this path for the external file.

Comment: You can also use loaderInfo.loaderURL property which contains the loaded swf's path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to pass an flash var (parameter) to the flash movie while embedding it to the html. This way you can tell Flash which is the correct path for the clip to be loaded (or even say which is the absolute root / current flash folder). Then load the swf from this specific domain!

Comment: It sound awesome, but can you give an exemple of code, like html and actionScript?

Comment: Hi there and sorry for the late response. Have you managed to figure it out, or still need some help

Comment: Yes, I found out. At the start of my code, I put:
Application.lienExterne=LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.lien.toString();
This takes the variable named "lien" in my html and I use the put like this:
Application.lienExterne+"techBoyMediasExternes/images/splash.png"
My html looks like this:
<param name=FlashVars value="lien={{ asset("bundles/public/projets/flash/") }}" />